# Is there a way to automatically update the documentation in an R package?

Tags: r, package, manual, roxygen

I used 'package.skeleton()' to generate .Rd help files a few months ago. I have edited these files, and I have also changed the functions, removed some functions, added others. Is there a function that automates updating the Rd files?

*update*

A nice package was just released called [Rd2roxygen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rd2roxygen/index.html), it is described by the author Yihui Xie on his [blog](http://yihui.name/en/2010/12/rd2roxygen-convert-rd-to-roxygen-documentation/).

As the name implies, this package allows one to retroactively insert documentation currently contained in .Rd into .R files. Sounds like a promising approach for both learning roxygen and for converting packages currently in development to R packages. Woo hoo. Thanks Yihui!

*Based on answers by Joshua and Yihui, the answer appears to be:* roxygen allows automatic updating of Rd files etc based on changes in the source .R code, and if I am not using roxygen currently, Rd2roxygen can help me migrate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Rd2roxygen` was designed to help package developers who have been "stuck" in the raw Rd files but want to switch to `roxygen` -- it can process Rd files and update the R scripts with roxygen comments. From then on, you can begin to enjoy the power of `roxygen`. So `Rd2roxygen` is not a direct answer, but it might help you with the transition.

Answer (score 9):

This doesn't specifically answer your question, but you may be interested in [Roxygen](http://roxygen.org/).

Comment: what are the advantages of roxygen over the tools described in "writing R extensions"?

Comment: Mainly that it creates the .Rd files for you based on extra information you add to the source .R files.

Comment: @David A very important advantage is that it makes it easy to write the documentation immediately after you wrote the code---you don't even have to switch files.  Then not only are the important details fresh in your head, but you can write the docs during the "woohoo! writing new code!" stage instead of the "ugh... have to go back and document it all" stage of production.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.

But you could try re-running `package.skeleton()` for new or changed functions and then merge this by hand.